# Object, Array or Array like objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

In javascript which one is more efficient? Which one is faster during iteration? And which one takes less time to fetch over network?

I am not expecting the answers that will be based on the utility methods that are attached to objects, arrays or array like objects.

To throw some more light over the scenario that I am talking about, please check the 2 options below.

**Option1**

```
["A1", "A2", "A3"]
```

**Option2**

```
{"0":"A1", "1": "A2", "2": "A3", "length": 3}
```

Which one is faster during iteration? And which one takes less time to fetch over network?

Comment: You seem to start from the false premise that arrays and objects are interchangeable. That's usually not the case. Each one has different use cases. So the general answer is: Use the right tool for the job. However, if you really need a different level of performance, use typed arrays. *"which one takes less time to fetch over network"* That question doesn't make sense. You cannot transfer an object or array over the network.

Comment: All three of your questions are entirely dependent on the value of your variable - be it a plain object or array - and how you plan to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that arrays would be the best, since they are only an array. If you use an object, it has many other properties to fetch.

But don't get me wrong, because objects are more useful than arrays in the right situation, but I think the fastest to fetch would be an array.

Comment: *"If you use an object, it has many other properties to fetch."* What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Stuff like built-in object methods and other information is needed for the object. If you use an array, it's as simple as a variable name, and the values inside.

Comment: What about all the built-in array methods (there are more built-in array methods than there are built-in object methods)?

Comment: It is more information to transfer. Although objects can be useful, arrays just have less data overall.

Comment: @GreenHawk1220—you can't say that without context like the same data presented as an object and as an array. Arrays *are* Objects after all.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with GreenHawk's answer. Arrays in JavaScript *are* simply plain objects with an array prototype. Thus, the indices of your data are actually integer => data.

This can be seen with the following snippet:

```js
var arr = ["javascript", "is", "a", "strange", "language."]

delete arr["3"]; // because an array is actually a map of "indicies" to values, strings work as well here.
console.log(arr.length); //=> 5
console.log(arr);
```

As far as iteration, using an array is probably your best bet because your browser may be able to optimize it (or at the very least JS makes it easier to iterate).

There should be very little size / transfer rate difference between the two, since an array's methods/properties are defined on its prototype (similar to a superclass in a classical language like Java), and thus not transferred over the network.

Answer (score 0):

> In JavaScript which one is more efficient?

Efficient in terms of what? Memory?

> Which one is faster during iteration?

Well, you have to iterate over the objects in different ways, so it's not apples-to-apples. If you want to compare these two loops:

```
for (value of option1);
for (key in option2) option[key];
```

The first might be moderately faster, say 25%. If you loop in a different way, using `forEach` for the array and `Object.keys(option2).forEach` for the object, the differences might be more pronounced. If the array is sparse, results could be different. The only way to know for sure is to run benchmarks, and the outcome could vary from engine to engine, or one version of an engine to the next.

> And which one takes less time to fetch over network?

The array form is smaller (less bytes), so it would take less time. Assuming the payload is gzipped, however, the difference is likely to be miniscule unless you are talking about thousands of values.

If your underlying data is semantically an array, why not just treat it as an array?